# Как работает оператор in в TypeScript (именно в TS а на в JS)?

Tags: typescript

Есть следующий код:

```
const formData = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 33,
    id: 1234,
};

type validateForm = {
    [key in keyof typeof formData]: boolean
};

// По сути этот код выше, создаёт тип следующего вида:
// type validateForm = {
//     firstName: boolean,
//     lastName: boolean,
//     age: boolean,
//     id: boolean,
// }
```

Вопрос №1.
В данном случае оператор `typeof` при объявлении типа, (не в исполняемом коде), работает иначе чем в JS, он приводит объект formData к типу.
Затем у полученного типа мы получаем ключи с помощью оператора keyof, по сути получаем строковый литерал `firstName | lastName | age | id`.
А вот что происходит дальше, не понятно.
Я так понимаю что здесь оператор `in` работает не так как в JavaScript и вызывает итерацию, с последовательной записью типа boolean в каждый ключ.
В документации ts не удаётся ничего найти про поведение оператора in, чтобы понять как он работает в TypeScript-е.

Вопрос №2.
Почему вот этот код выдаёт ошибку?

```
type keys = key in keyof typeof formData;
// думал получить кортеж следующего вида type keys: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age', 'id'], но получил ошибку
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос, на каких данных происходит ошибка? Или какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Ошибка в коде во 2-м вопросе. Вся строка по сути подчёркивается и не воспринимается TypeScript-ом.
Какой-то конкретный результат я не хочу получить, я хочу понять как работает оператор `in`.
Так "под капотом" происходят судя по всему какие-то итерации, я хочу понять что именно там происходит, чтобы понять в каких случаях я могу применять этот оператор.

Comment: Тип должен быть чуму то равен ) У вас даже синтаксис отличается. Напишите по второму вопросу вот так и ошибка уйдет `type keys = {
    [key in keyof typeof formData]: any
}`

Comment: Не ну то что эта конструкция работает в фигурных скобках и используется для формирования ключей объекта, это и так понятно. Я хотел узнать, могу ли я воспользоваться этой конструкцией ВНЕ объекта? И если нет, то почему?

Comment: Насчёт того что тип должен быть чему-то равен. Опечатался, уже исправил двоеточие на равно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (тип-отображение), специальный синтаксис позволяющий задать множество свойств на основе множества ключей. Отдельной от этой функциональности версии оператора `in` не существует. Если необходимо проитерироваться по юниону для этого можно использовать [Distributive Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) (распределённый условный тип). Если же необходимо получить именно кортеж, то простого способа для этого, к сожалению, не придумали. Можете посмотреть некоторые варианты решения [здесь](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298).

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за ссылки на документацию. Т.е. получается оператор `in` в TS действительно используется не так как в JS (в данном контексте). А похож на цикл for...in в JS, которой используется для перебора всех типов в union типе. Вот этот момент я как раз хотел уточнить.